# DryIoc: register decorator with two interfaces, retrieve the decorator instance when resolving the other interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

Here is a somewhat simplified description of the problem I'm trying to solve:
I have a service (e.g. a repository) implementing an interface that I need to inject as a dependency:

`public class Service : IService { ... }`

I'd like to add a decorator, for example one that add caching that also implements another interface:

```
public class CachingService: IService, IFlushable
{
  public CachingService(IService decoratee) { ... }

  public void Flush() { ... }
}

public interface IFlushable
{
  public void Flush();
}
```

Normally, I'd just register the CachingService as an implementation of IService as as decorator, using `Setup.Decorator` or `Setup.DecoratorWith`.
But in this case I have an extra requirement related to the IFlushable interface.
There will be several different services with their own decorators, all of them implementing the both the decorated service interface and IFlushable. I need to inject all the IFlushable decorators as a dependency to be able to flush all the caches on request.

```
public class CacheHandler
{
  public CacheHandler(IFlushable[] cache) { ... }

  public void FlushAllCaches() { ... }
}
```

The problem is that this CacheHandler must receive the same decorator instances that were applied to the Service classes.

I have tried several solutions using `RegisterMapping` and tried to scope the resolution of the caches to their decorated services, but I could not make it work.
Either the I receive an error that the container cannot resolve the decorators (which makes sense) or I need to register the decorators themselves, but in the latter case the CacheHandler will receive a new set of IFlushable instances.

The more I think about the more I feel that what I'm trying to achieve here might not even by possible using a DI container. I mean maybe I'm solve this the wrong way.
My question is if my approach is valid and/or how can I get all the applied IFLushable decorator instances as a dependency.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this easily, independently on which DI container you pick. I'm not that familiar with DryIoc, but you might have more luck in extracting the `IFlushable` behavior from the decorator and injecting it into the decorator. This allows the decorator onto a service that allows caching results and allows flushing its cache. This makes it easier to inject or resolve a list of cachables/flushable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would agree with [@Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) to consider inverting the control and injecting the `IFlushable` into the `CachingService`.

Second, you may realize the decorator for `IService` a bit differently - no need to implement it in `CachingService`:

```cs
    [Test]
    public void Answer()
    {
        var c = new Container();

        c.Register<IService, Service>(Reuse.Singleton);
        c.RegisterMany<CachingService>(Reuse.Singleton); // registers both CashingService and IFlushable with the same implementing instance
        c.RegisterDelegate<CachingService, IService>(cs => cs.GetDecoratedService(), setup: Setup.Decorator);

        var s = c.Resolve<IService>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(s);
        var cs = c.Resolve<CachingService>();
        Assert.IsTrue(cs.ServiceDecorated); // check the service indeed is decorated
        
        var f = c.Resolve<IFlushable>();
        Assert.AreSame(cs, f); // check that the flushable and caching service are the same instance
    }

    public interface IService { }

    public class Service : IService { }

    // no need to implement IService for the decorator, we may use its method instead
    public class CachingService : IFlushable
    {
        public readonly IService Service;
        public bool ServiceDecorated;

        public CachingService(IService service) => Service = service;

        public IService GetDecoratedService()
        {
            ServiceDecorated = true; // do something with decorated service
            return Service; 
        }

        public void Flush() { }
    }

    public interface IFlushable
    {
        public void Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late answer, I got temporarily transferred to another project. Coming back to this after a break had its benefits; it's clear to me now that the suggestion from @Steven is the right way to go. However the workaround in your answer might come handy some day, thanks!